# SQL join have a double the column i want

Tags: mysql, join, mysql-workbench

Hello I was trying to make a new view by Joining 2 View. I have 1 view filled with a question id and the number of correct answer. Then another with the number of wrong answer. I want to have it merged so its just question_id, correct_answer, wrong_answer.
Im using MySQL workbench to do my queries.

This the query for making the correct answer view

```
CREATE VIEW v_question_history_correct
    AS
SELECT question_id, COUNT(correctness) AS true_answer FROM skripsi_database_soal.questions_history
        WHERE correctness = 'true'
        GROUP BY question_id;
```

This is the query for making the wrong answer view

```
CREATE VIEW v_question_history_false
AS    
SELECT question_id, COUNT(correctness) AS false_answer FROM skripsi_database_soal.questions_history
    WHERE correctness = 'false'
    GROUP BY question_id;
```

This is the query i use to join both of them

```
SELECT * FROM v_question_history_correct JOIN v_question_history_false 
    ON v_question_history_correct.question_id = v_question_history_false.question_id;
```

This is What i get
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oIdu.png)

This is the content of correct answer
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVoee.png)

This is the content of wrong answer
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tv23P.png)

Any help would be appreciated. To add Im still new to the JOIN stuff so I might have written a wrong syntax to begin with. Thanks

Edit:
Both of the answer solved it thank you all
Reasoning i make View is just in case I need to use the data that has just true or false i can just use the view instead of doing full select. Because in the future i will combine that view with data from another table.

Comment: Any particular reason why you creating views? Also with inner join driven from trues you will only find false answers where the exist in true. Research mysql conditional aggregation

Comment: `.. FROM v_question_history_correct JOIN v_question_history_false USING ( question_id ) ..` will produce only one column copy in the output. The values are taken from first table (for any JOIN except RIGHT when the value is taken from 2nd table), but there is no difference for INNER JOIN. You must refer to the column from 2nd table using table alias, the name without the table alias refers to the column of the first table.

Comment: *`SELECT * ..`* Never use an asterisk (exclusion - `COUNT(*)`), specify definite columns names with needed table aliases explicitly always.

Comment: [mre] [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your data

```
CREATE TABLE v_question_history_correct(question_id int ,true_answer  int);
insert into v_question_history_correct
(question_id,true_answer) VALUES 
(5,7),
(6,8),
(7,8);

CREATE TABLE v_question_history_false(question_id int ,false_answer   int);
insert into v_question_history_false
(question_id,false_answer ) VALUES 
(2,7),
(1,7),
(6,1),
(7,1);
```

use `full join` equivalent in mysql

```
SELECT VC.question_id,true_answer ,false_answer 
FROM v_question_history_correct VC
LEFT JOIN v_question_history_false  VF
    ON VC.question_id = VF.question_id;
UNION
SELECT VF.question_id,true_answer ,false_answer 
FROM v_question_history_correct VC
RIGHT JOIN v_question_history_false  VF
    ON VC.question_id = VF.question_id;
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=7e7ab8cce8430992d0af568d2d6619af)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    SELECT coalesce(v_question_history_correct.question_id,f.question_id,v_question_history_false.question_id) 'question_id',true_answer,false_answer 
FROM v_question_history_correct 
    full JOIN v_question_history_false     ON v_question_history_correct.question_id = v_question_history_false.question_id;
```

Comment: full join does  not exist in mysql

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).